# Color SVG font not displaying in color in LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex, miktex, fontspec

I am using this test font, which supposedly should have colors for the letters abcdeABCDE: https://github.com/faiuwle/qucheanya/blob/main/ColorFont-SVG.ttf

This is what I'm trying:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{fontspec}  
\newfontface\testfont{ColorFont-SVG.ttf}[RawFeature=colr]  
\begin{document}  
 
{\testfont abcdeABCDE} 
 
\end{document}
```

It doesn't seem to matter whether I run LuaLaTeX using TexMaker (the IDE I'm using) or run it on the command line, either way the text is only in black.  What do I need to do here?

Edit:

From a response on this question, I tried with this modified code:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{fontspec}  
\newfontface\testfont{ColorFont-SVG.ttf}[RawFeature=+svg]  
\begin{document}
{\testfont abcdeABCDE} 
\end{document}
```

and installing Inkscape and adding C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin to the PATH, and running `lualatex -shell-escape` to compile.  This results in it hanging indefinitely.  If I run it in TexMaker with the -interaction=nonstopmode flag, it finishes with this error:

```
[string "-- luatex-core security and io overloads ....."]:81: bad argument #2 to
'io_popen' (invalid mode).
<to be read again>
relax
l.5 {\testfont
abcdeABCDE}
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.
! Font \TU/ColorFont-SVG.ttf(0)/m/n/10=[ColorFont-SVG.ttf]:mode=node;script=latn
;language=dflt;+svg; at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
<to be read again>
```

Comment: Does `Renderer=HarfBuzz` work?

Comment: @Davislor, for me `Renderer=HarfBuzz` does not work (with or without `-shell-escape`).

Comment: @DavidPurton Okay, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If I slightly adjust your font loading option to use:

```
\newfontface\testfont{ColorFont-SVG.ttf}[RawFeature=+svg]
```

And run with (to allow `inkscape` to be called):

```
lualatex -shell-escape
```

Then I get colour output.

### MWE

```
% TeX Program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{fontspec}  
\newfontface\testfont{ColorFont-SVG.ttf}[RawFeature=+svg]  
\begin{document}
{\testfont abcdeABCDE} 
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I get this error when I run this:

```
(./qucheanya.toc [1{C:/Users/drago/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex
.map}]) [2][string "-- luatex-core security and io overloads ....."]:81: bad ar
gument #2 to 'io_popen' (invalid mode).
<to be read again>
relax
l.14 {\testfont
              abcdeABCDE}
```

Then the text does not display in the PDF at all.

Comment: @faiuwle, is that from the MWE exactly as I have it? There is nothing there that should produce a `toc` file. Try a clean file in a clean working directory first. Also you run Windows. Do you have Inkscape installed? Is Inkscape in your path? I don't run windows and can't test how things work under that environment. (I use TeXLive under Linux.)

Comment: Yes, that document also has a table of contents.  If I run just your code I get this error: (C:/Users/drago/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)[string
"-- luatex-core security and io overloads ....."]:81: bad argument #2 to 'io_po
pen' (invalid mode).
<to be read again>
relax
l.5 {\testfont
             abcdeABCDE}

I don't know if I have Inkscape installed.  What do I have to do to install it?

Comment: I installed Inkscape from the .msi on the Inkscape website, and I still get the same error.

Comment: @faiuwle, hmmm, sorry. I can't help you much with Windows issues. Maybe ask a new question with my code, a link to this question and ask specifically about MikTeX and Windows. (The only thing to check is that `inkscape` is in your path, otherwise `lualatex` can't find it.)

Comment: I edited my path to include the path to inkscape, however, now when I run the command it just hangs indefinitely.  Manually running inkscape from the terminal does the same thing.

Comment: @faiuwle, ooo. Time to install Linux? ;)

Comment: I have linux, but I have to reinstall grub to access it normally and I don't want to do that right now.

Comment: I removed and readded the path back and now it doesn't hang indefinitely when I run the command, instead it launches some kind of GUI.  Maybe that is the problem, if lualatex is trying to launch a GUI now?

Comment: @faiuwle, I don't know. Under Linux, `inkscape` is called in a headless mode.

Comment: If I put -shell-escape into the command for TexMaker, then it finishes, but with this error: ! Font \TU/ColorFont-SVG.ttf(0)/m/n/10=[ColorFont-SVG.ttf]:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+svg; at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
<to be read again>

Comment: @faiuwle Sorry, I'm out of ideas. Edit your question with an update showing relevant log you get with my code and hopefully someone else will add an answer.